# decoding the symbols of the Abracon series ASTMLP marking

Tags: identification, packages, markings

I purchased the ASTMLPE-100,000MHZ-L JET component. I would like to figure out what is encrypted in the component labeling.

[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet say on this mattr?

Comment: There is no information about labeling for these series in the documentation

Comment: @WangYun If it's not specified in the datasheet, then you're out of luck. Only Abracon knows what these codes mean since there is no universal standard.